# How to find nested classes in VB.Net using reflection?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have the following class :

```
Public Class F
    Public Class A
        Public Class C

        End Class
    End Class

    Public Class B

    End Class
End Class
```

And I'm writing a function to return the embedded classes of class F. Basically I'm expecting the function to return A & B types...

```
Public Function FindInternalClasses(ByVal TBaseType As Object) As List(Of Type)
    Dim baseType = TBaseType.GetType
    Dim assembly = baseType.Assembly
    Dim Output As New List(Of Type)

    For Each Item In assembly.GetTypes
        If Item.IsSubclassOf(baseType) Then
            Output.Add(Item)
        End If
    Next

    Return Output
End Function
```

When running this function, it always return nothing. (The condition **"If Item.IsSubclassOf(baseType)"**  is always false.)

Does anyone know please what is missing to this code ?

Comment: A, C and B are not "sub classes" - they do not inherit from A or anything else (at least as far as that code shows).  They are internal or nested classes.

Comment: Are they your classes you are trying to find or are you rummaging thru some other assembly?

Comment: Yes Plutonix, sorry for the miswording, Indeed, they are internal classes. Do you know how return only these internal classes please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your starting point is, so I am guessing.  `SubClassing` (original post) refers to one class inheriting from some parent class:

```
Public [MustInherit] Class FooBar
   ...
End Class

Public Class Foo : Inherits FooBar
   ...
End Class
```

Properties and methods defines in `FooBar` are inherited by `Foo` which may be overridden or shadowed out.  But that is not what you have.  Class `A` and `B` are simply nested classes of `F`, and `C` is nested within `F.B`.

These are easy to find using the `baseType`, which appears to be an instance in your code:

```
Dim baseType = TBaseType.GetType

For Each Item In baseType.GetNestedTypes
    Console.WriteLine(Item.FullName)
Next
```

To find nested Types from a Type rather than instance, use `Dim baseType = GetType(FooBar)` as the starting point.  If you know a bit about what you are after, you can get more specific by specifying `BindingFlags`.  For instance include only nested Types which are private:

```
For Each Item In baseType.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
     ...
```

But it need not be a loop:

```
Dim Output = New List(Of Type)(TBaseType.GetType.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public))
```

I am not sure why your code goes thru all the Types in the assembly since you have the starting baseType / actual outer type; if/when there is some good reason for that, use Hans' method.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You have about 95% of the function. The following should do the trick.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim obj As New F()

        Dim result = GetSubClasses(obj)

        For Each t As Type In result
            Console.WriteLine(t)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetSubClasses(ByRef obj As Object) As List(Of Type)
        Dim baseType = obj.GetType()
        Dim output As New List(Of Type)

        For Each t As Type In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            If t.IsSubclassOf(obj.GetType()) Then
                output.Add(t)
            End If
        Next

        Return output
    End Function
End Module

Public Class F

End Class

Public Class A : Inherits F

End Class

Public Class B : Inherits F

End Class

Public Class C : Inherits A

End Class
```

Output of the following would be:

```
ConsoleApplication1.A
ConsoleApplication1.B
ConsoleApplication1.C
```

A and B inherit from F. Because C inherits from A, it is also considered a subclass of F.

Answer (score 0):

They are *nested* types.  Nested types don't have any inheritance relationship to their outer type so IsSubclassOf() cannot work.  The only property that makes them distinctive is the Type.DeclaringType property, it references their outer type.  So your code ought to look like:

```
Public Function FindNestedTypes(ByVal outerType As Type) As List(Of Type)
    Dim output As New List(Of Type)
    For Each item In outerType.Assembly.GetTypes()
        Dim declarer = item.DeclaringType
        Do While declarer IsNot Nothing
            If declarer Is outerType Then
                output.Add(item)
                Exit Do
            End If
            declarer = declarer.DeclaringType
        Loop
    Next
    Return output
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```
For Each t As Type In FindNestedTypes(GetType(F))
    Console.WriteLine(t.FullName)
Next
```

Output:

```
ConsoleApplication1.F+A
ConsoleApplication1.F+B
ConsoleApplication1.F+A+C
```

If you don't want to find class C then remove the Do While loop.